# JComponent subclass not appearing

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent

Okay. I was writing my **Ball** class and the ball is not displayed. I tried adding other components to my container and they are displayed, so I think it is safe to assume that the problem is my ball. The class code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JComponent;


public class Ball extends JComponent {

public Ball() {
    ballX  = (Window.WINDOW_WIDTH - BALL_DIAMETER) / 2;
    ballY  = (Window.WINDOW_HEIGHT - BALL_DIAMETER) / 2;
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawRect(5, 5, 50, 50);
    g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    g.fillOval(ballX, ballY, BALL_DIAMETER, BALL_DIAMETER);
    g.dispose();

}
public void setX(int x) {
    ballX = x;
}
public void setY(int y) {
    ballY = y;
}

private int ballX;
private int ballY;
public static final int BALL_DIAMETER = 30;
}
```

The first rect was used for testing. It doesn't appear neither....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your component has a preferred size larger than (0, 0):

```
@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return new Dimension(500, 500);
}
```

Comment: Yes! Now they appear on the screen. I set them equal to the size of my application. Thank you.

Comment: But shouldn't my balls preffered size be the size of the ball itself? **BALL_DIAMETER**? Because in this case it doesn't appear.

Comment: It doesn't appear because you don't paint the ball at (0, 0), but at (ballX, ballY), which is outside of the dimensions of your ball.

Comment: Okay. But if I have two components with prefferedsize equal to the windows only one appears - the one which was added first

Comment: The layout of the componentds depends on the layout managers of the panel where you add your components. By default, the content pane of a JFrame uses a BorderLayout, and only one component can be at the center of a BorderLayout. Your component should not have the size of the window as their preferred size. They should have ... their preferred size. And of course, they should paint themselves though that they look good when they have their preferred size.

Answer (score 1):

Not seeing the code that adds the ball to a container, it's a little hard to answer your question.

However, there are a few problems with your code:

1. You're setting the location of the ball in the constructor, using some constants - Assuming you want to paint the ball in the middle of the component, you should calculate the location in the paintComponent method by calling getSize and doing the math on the spot
2. You dispose of the Graphics object at the end of the paintComponent method even though you didn't create it, don't do that, remove that method call (that's probably the culprit)
3. You're not keeping the state of the Graphics object. Either create a copy (using the create method of the Graphics object) and disposing of it at the end, or by restoring the state you changed at the end of the method (the Color that was set before you changed it to Color.GREEN)

Comment: 1. Well the point is to set it's start location. Afterwards it will be set using setX and setY methods.
2. I removed it.
3. Why do I need a copy of it?

Comment: Since you're changing its state, and the same Graphic object is used along the entire component hierarchy. By changing the state and not restoring it (or using a copy), you're also inadvertently affecting other stuff that you're unaware of.